# Can't receive deliver_sm (SMPP)

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway, smpp

I'm sending SMS by PHP, SMPP protocol and must use Net_SMPP library. After sending SMS (it comes to phone normally) I need to receive answer (deliver_sm PDU from SMSC). But listening of it hasn't take effect. My reciver's code:

```
$host = '*********';
$port = '****';
$login = '*****';
$password = '*******';

/*
 * There is sending of SMS
*/

$smsc = new Net_SMPP_Client($host, $port);
$smsc->connect();

$resp = $smsc->bind(
  array(
      'system_id' => $login,
      'password' => $password,
      'addr_ton' => NET_SMPP_TON_INTL,
      'addr_npi' => NET_SMPP_NPI_ISDN,         
      'system_type' => ''
  ), 
  $typeBind
);

if (!is_object($resp) || $resp->isError()) {
  die('CANNOT BIND');
}

$resp = $smsc->readPDU();
if (is_object($resp) && !$resp->isError()) {
    //This is needble point 
}
```

SMS-provider says that he'd sent deliver_sm and my script responded deliver_sm_resp with error "ESME receiver temporary app error code" (errcode 0x00000064).

Intresting that after sending SMS to special "gate"-number deliver_sm will **normally** come to me and handle by my script.

What did I go wrong? Help me please! Or say me if any other info needs for solving.

Comment: is your script running as a daemon ?

Comment: Yes, it'll runinng by cron.

Comment: You need a stateful session established with your provider and not a connect/disconnect script

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

There was other daemon running by same login on other server! It was receiving all requests